# Vectors pointers with vector slices for Tree generation from preorder and inorder vectors

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I'm getting the following error:

solution.cpp: In member function buildTree
Line 26: Char 62: error: no matching function for call to 'Solution::buildTree(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, int>::value_type*, std::vector*)'
         root->left = buildTree(&preorder[index],&inorderslice);
                                                              ^

In this code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
        if(preorder.empty() || inorder.empty())
            return NULL;
        if(preorder.size() == 1) // preorder and inorder should always have the same length
        {
            TreeNode *node = new TreeNode(preorder[0]);
            return node;
        }
        // current root is the first entry of preorder
        TreeNode *root = new TreeNode(preorder[0]);
        // find the index of this number in inorder
        std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find(inorder.begin(), inorder.end(), preorder[0]);
        int index = std::distance(inorder.begin(), it);
        std::vector<int> inorderslice = std::vector<int>(inorder.begin(), inorder.begin() + index);
        root->left = buildTree(&preorder[index],&inorderslice); // This line is a problem
        root->right = buildTree(&preorder[index+1],&inorder[index+1]); // This line is a problem
        return root;

    }
};
```

I'm trying to solve a problem to generate a tree from its preorder and inorder traverse vectors.

I'm trying to do it recursively but I'm having a problem matching the variable types of the function doing the recursion.

```
    TreeNode* buildTree(vector<int>& preorder, vector<int>& inorder) {
```

This header is receiving a pointer to a vector of ints.

In my algorithm I'm trying to slice the input vectors to only use parts of it in my recursion:

```
        std::vector<int> inorderslice = std::vector<int>(inorder.begin(), inorder.begin() + index);
```

For the preorder vector I just want to cut the elements in front (the ones before index), so I thought I'd just pass a pointer to that element of the vector.

For the inorder vector I want to cut the elements AFTER index.

In a pythonic way this would just be
preorder[index:]
inorder[:index]

But I'm getting an error in the call to the function.

How do I do this in C++?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions take references; you're passing pointers.

There is a confusion here about what `&` means.

It is any of:

- the bitwise *AND* operator when applied in between two expressions
- the "address-of" operator when applied to one operator, resulting in a pointer

  - this is what you're doing in your function calls
- "reference" when added to a type name

  - this is what you're putting in your function parameters

In short, remove `&` from your calls, and review the chapter in your C++ book about using references.

> This header is receiving a pointer to a vector of ints.

No, it isn't.

Comment: This is what I first thought. In fact, I had it without the & at the start, but without it I get this error: 

solution.cpp: no matching function for call to 'Solution::buildTree(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int>, int>::value_type&, std::vector<int>&)'
         root->left = buildTree(preorder[index],inorderslice); // This line is a problem
                                                            ^

Comment: You need to think more carefully about your datatypes. Your function accepts vectors, but you're passing it ints? Why? Perhaps you should switch to iterator ranges?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the reference to a specific index in the vector. I just started c++ and don't really know how to use iterators. Is it impossible to do what I'm trying to do without iterators?

Comment: But the function doesn't take that thing. It takes a [reference to a] vector.

Comment: So a reference to the n-th element of a vector isn't a reference to a vector? Similar to *(vector+n)?

Comment: @JoaoAntunes *So a reference to the n-th element of a vector isn't a reference to a vector?* -- No.  The nth element of a vector is of type `T` for a `vector<T>`, thus a reference to the nth element is a `T&`, not a `vector<T>&`.

Comment: Then is there any way I can solve my code without structural change? Or do I need to approach it another way? Is there a way for me to pass the reference to the n-th element of a vector? Sorry for the beginner questions.

Comment: `&preorder[index]`  -- This is an `int *`, i.e a pointer to a single `int`.  You really should get more familiar with the types you're dealing with.  You use the terms "reference" when what you have are addresses / pointers.  In C++, a reference has a specific meaning, and it doesn't mean "pointer".  A vector is a class that is a wrapper for a dynamic array.  Getting "pointers within it" is not giving you a "cut down" version of the vector.  I think that is where you wrote the code with that mistaken notion.